# Birth tourists, American visas, citizens and integration, how does it play out?

Tags: united-states, immigration

I recently read an [article](http://www.latimes.com/local/lanow/la-me-ln-birth-tourism-persists-20161220-story.html) about chinese woman going to the U.S. and giving birth to chinese babies who would be chinese Americans. To put the article simply what happens is -

- The chinese women either truthfully shares that she is pregnant and
  going to United States to get medical help OR
- Doesn't share that she is pregnant (going to States very early in pregnancy, say 1 to 2 months when it doesn't began to show)
- Then they let nature take it course and a U.S. citizen is born.
- They either take the baby back to China OR
- The whole family relocates to U.S.

One of the other reasons that some women gave were -

> In Shanghai, she says, the buildings are tall and modern, but the rent
>   is high. The skyline is beautiful, but the air isn’t clean and the
>   food isn’t safe. The airport is architecturally impressive but
>   inconvenient.The people speak her language, but they are always
>   judging and comparing, evaluating the clothes she wears, the home and
>   neighborhood she lives in, the school her children will attend. A life
>   in America is a break from all of that.
>
> “Here people are not so competitive, trying to wear better clothes and
>   use better things,” Tracy said. “I don’t even have to wear makeup.”

Now for the sake of argument, let's say they do get away with it and a child is born who as per the report become naturalized U.S. citizens at birth.

For the parents to remain with their children though, they would have to go through the gruelling understanding of language, laws, customs and whatever is necessary in order to become a legally Chinese-American citizen. My questions unfortunately are two -

a. Aren't the women knowingly getting into this trap where there is possibility they may have to leave the children in hands of strangers (maybe child protection services and possibility of abuse at foster homes) ?

b. In case the parents are deported, does a child/young baby have any other option than a foster home ?

Comment: (a) is un-answerable in SE format. (b) is a legal question for Law.SE, not politics.SE.

Comment: The children are natural born US citizens. It's impossible to be a "naturalized US citizen at birth." The parents cannot stay because the child can't sponsor them for immigration until she or he reaches 21 years of age. The usual procedure is to return to the parents' country of citizenship (in this case, China), where the child is generally also a citizen. Then, when the child is old enough, she or he can move to the US to study or work if she or he wants. Once the child is 21, the parents can apply for green cards (they don't have to become citizens to stay in the US).

Comment: Why would they have to leave their child? Does the US have a habit of deporting parents but keeping the babies?

Comment: I asked as I had seen movies which showed that, but the movies which I remember had muslim families and this was after 9/11 so maybe that would be an outlier.

Comment: "Aren't the women knowingly getting into this trap where there is possibility they may have to leave the children in hands of strangers (maybe child protection services and possibility of abuse at foster homes) ?" No. There is no trap. Usually, when a parent moves, the parent brings their children with them (no matter if the move is within the same country or to a different country). The parent would only be leaving the child to others if the parent chooses to.

Comment: "In case the parents are deported, does a child/young baby have any other option than a foster home ?" Again, as above, it's the parent's options, not the child's options. The parent decides what to do with the child. The parent is responsible for taking care of their children, usually by taking their children with them whenever they move; otherwise they arrange for someone to take care of their children. If they choose to abandon their children, then yes, their parental rights will be terminated and the child taken by the state. This is true regardless of whether the parent is deported or not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Aren't the women knowingly getting into this trap where there is possibility they may have to leave the children in hands of strangers (maybe child protection services and possibility of abuse at foster homes) ?

There may be a misconception among some of these parents that having a baby in America will allow them to become citizens.  Some parents may not care, thinking that their child's future will be better off even without them.

Non-residents can petition for immigrant status, but that is a long way from citizenship.

[PolitiFact](http://www.politifact.com/truth-o-meter/statements/2010/aug/06/lindsey-graham/illegal-immigrants-anchor-babies-birthright/) did some fact checking regarding the "anchor baby" issue and found that the benefits are highly dependent on the time frame you are thinking about:

- In the **short term** there are benefits for undocumented aliens who raise their child in America. The child is a citizen, and will help the family qualify for WIC, Medicare, and other programs.
- In the **medium term** there are really no benefits to the parents. The child can't sponsor them for citizenship until they turn 21, and if the parents live in the country illegally they will have to leave for 10 years before reapplying.
- In the **long term** the child could potentially sponsor the parents in their endeavor to become citizens. However, this is a 21 year wait to start a many years-long process.

> In case the parents are deported, does a child/young baby have any other option than a foster home ?

Foster care (and other social services) are a matter of state policy, so the details will vary depending on where they are. However, if the child stays in the country and the parent doesn't they will generally need to either be adopted or sent to foster care.

Adoption through the state system can be a long and complex process; private adoptions can be done much more quickly if a willing parent is located.